# Monaco editor registerCompletionItemProvider

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using registerCompletionItemProvider to provide suggestions for sql language. I need to use it multiple time because my suggestions may change. Each time my suggestions changes I have registered new completionProvider and end with calling multiple providers. Is there a way to unregister previous providers or update current one?

Comment: Can you explain why you need multiple providers? Since the provider is invoked dynamically, you should be able to adjust its output on demand.

Comment: `registerCompletionItemProvider` returns a `IDisposable` object so you can call `.dispose` but as @MikeLischke has mentioned, the provider is invoked dynamically so you can just adjust its output on demand, reading the values from variables not need to treat them as static or so